# Trying to understand the difference between IBM Watson's Virtual Agent and Conversational Agent/API

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-virtual-agent

I am currently evaluating IBM's new Virtual Agent service which seems very similar to the Conversational Agent/API available - Are somehow both related?

Can the training / process flow established in Conversational Agent/API be leveraged in Virtual Agent?

Answer (score 0):

Watson Virtual Agent(WVA) is a SaaS which allows you to deploy a fully functional Watson Conversation system with little to no coding/knowledge of how Conversation works. It uses the Conversation API.

You can hook in Watson Conversation workspaces to WVA. In the related training component, there should be an option to override with a conversation workspace.